# How to patch application running on weblogic/atg?

Tags: java, weblogic, weblogic-10.x, atg

Assume we have a java EAR file called MySimpleApp.ear running on weblogic 10.3.6 and ATG 10.2 which looks like this:

> MySimple.ear 
>            |
>            |----WebModule.war 
>            |----Services.jar 
>            |      |----foo.class 
>            |      |----bar.class 
>            |----Config.jar 
>               |----foo.properties 
>               |----bar.properties

I would like to patch just the `foo.class` and the `foo.properties` without redeploying the entire application and accept that a restart might be required.

What is the recommended way of doing this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you looked at the redeploy docs? There is plenty of documentation out there. That said, if you're willing to restart... just patch the whole thing anyway.

http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E15051_01/wls/docs103/deployment/redeploy.html

There are 4 options:

- Production Redeployment - redeploy alongside an existing app
- In-Place Redeployment of Applications and Modules - will replace application immediately and may interrupt clients
- Partial Redeployment of Static Files - static files like images, not running classes
- Partial Redeployment of J2EE Modules - potentially what you want, update an individual module